# Restrict SQL output to items found only in subquery

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

Ok, given this example, can you point me in the right direction to restrict the output of this query to results found only in the where clause.  I'll explain more..

```
SELECT
ServerName=substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,patindex('%"%',substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,80))-1)
/* ,MN.object_text */, p.name
FROM
[openview].[dbo].[sto_ov_managednode] MN
left outer join [openview].[dbo].[OV_PM_PolicyOnNode] PON
on pon.nodeid = mn.name
left outer join [openview].[dbo].[OV_PM_PolicyVersion] PV
on PV.policyversionid = pon.policyversionid
left outer join [openview].[dbo].[OV_PM_Policy] P
on P.PolicyId = pv.policyid
where p.name not in (select Name from dbo.OV_PM_Policy where PolicyId = any(select PolicyId from dbo.OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment where GroupId = '18681abc-097d-41cd-9782-e28d9a9f5fc4'))
and substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%AgentBinaryFormatId%',MN.object_text)+22,1) <> '0' /* exclude non-managed nodes */
and substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%OsVersionId%',MN.object_text)+14,2) = '18' /* include only Windows OS devices */
ORDER BY ServerName, name;
```

Lets say this returns all the servernames with a p.name not in my query. That's what it is supposed to do as written... but I only want that servername if it doesn't have one of those policies...and only if it doesn't have one of those... not listing other policies it may have.. but aren't in that result set... I've tried different joins, and used not in.... exists not exists... the issue.. is, when I use those.. it doesn't really change anything.

Think of a folder structure..... that p.name is looking in a folder and finding all the policy names inside.  There are many folders and many other policies.... but in this I only care about those in that folder.  So if server A has all the policies in that folder I don't want to see it.. If it has other policies I don't care... but if it's missing even one of the policies from that given folder I want to know about it.

So basically I want the output it is giving me currently.. but only if the policy found was in that group to begin with.  So I need to restrict my output to only return servers missing policies from that group.

Updated -- sqlfiddle information and better example...thanks Mark for the sqlfiddle setup

```
create table sto_ov_managednode (
object_text varchar(100),
name varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyOnNode (
nodeid varchar(100),
policyversionid varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyVersion (
policyversionid varchar(100) unique,
policyid varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_Policy (
Name varchar(100),
PolicyId varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment (
PolicyId varchar(100),
GroupId varchar(100),
PolicyVerisonId varchar(100) unique
);

insert into sto_ov_managednode values ('Caption ---Server1"---AgentBinaryFormatId---OsVersionId---18--','node1');
insert into sto_ov_managednode values ('Caption ---Server2"---AgentBinaryFormatId---OsVersionId---18--','node2');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node1','policyversionID1');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node1','policyversionID4');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node2','policyversionID1');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid1','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid2','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid3','policyid2');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid4','policyid2');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid5','policyid3');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversionid6','policyid3');


insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy A','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy B','policyid2');
insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy C','policyid3');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment values ('policyid1','Base Windows','policyversionid2');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment values ('policyid2','Base Windows','policyversionid4');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment values ('policyid3','Extra Windows','policyversionid5');
```

Now the output is this..

```
nodeName    policyName
node1       policy C
node2       policy B
node2       policy C
```

You'll notice that this is basically correct.. but I don't want to see Policy C as it's not in the Base Windows Group.... I only need to see a policy if it's missing from a server...AND is included in the group I used to search for..

[New SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/560bb/1)

```
Final Update
```

This is the final sql statement that did in fact work.  Thanks for the effort, I appreciate it.

```
select ServerName=substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,patindex('%"%',substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,80))-1), "Policy" = P.name
FROM OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment PGA
left join OV_PM_Policy P on PGA.PolicyId = P.PolicyId
left join OV_PM_PolicyVersion PV on P.PolicyId = PV.policyid
cross join sto_ov_managednode MN
where PGA.GroupId = '18681abc-097d-41cd-9782-e28d9a9f5fc4'
and substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%AgentBinaryFormatId%',MN.object_text)+22,1) <> '0' /* exclude non-managed nodes */
and substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%OsVersionId%',MN.object_text)+14,2) = '18' /* include only Windows OS devices */
except
select ServerName=substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,patindex('%"%',substring(MN.object_text,patindex ('%Caption %',MN.object_text)+11,80))-1), P.name as policyName
from sto_ov_managednode MN
left join OV_PM_PolicyOnNode PON on pon.nodeid = mn.name
left join OV_PM_PolicyVersion PV on PV.policyversionid = pon.policyversionid
left join OV_PM_Policy P on P.PolicyId = pv.policyid
left join OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment PGA on P.PolicyId = PGA.PolicyId
where PGA.GroupId = '18681abc-097d-41cd-9782-e28d9a9f5fc4'
Order by ServerName, Policy;
```

Comment: I think a simpler way to go may be to left join it and in your where clause say 'where policy is null' (which would only bring back those servers where the policy is missing. And the missing policy), 

If that doesn't help could you possibly set up an sql fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com/) demonstrating the problem?

Comment: The problem with that.. is this an HP database.. and it's crazy complicated, at least to me and contains Instance Of WMI fields, hense the substring stuff.  I'm not sure I could replicate all that in sqlfiddle.  It's also TSQL and I'm not the DB owner.  so Where is Null returns nothing, as no server will be void of policy.  A server may have 100 policies.. but I'm only concerned with knowing that it's missing one of the 2x policies in that folder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope I understood your schema enough to correctly respond.

SQLFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/baffd/35

Set up data:

```
create table sto_ov_managednode (
  object_text varchar(100),
  name varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyOnNode (
  nodeid varchar(100),
  policyversionid varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyVersion (
  policyversionid varchar(100),
  policyid varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_Policy (
  name varchar(100),
  PolicyId varchar(100)
);

create table OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment (
  PolicyId varchar(100),
  GroupId varchar(100)
);

insert into sto_ov_managednode values ('Caption ---Server1"---AgentBinaryFormatId---OsVersionId---18--','node1');
insert into sto_ov_managednode values ('Caption ---Server2"---AgentBinaryFormatId---OsVersionId---18--','node2');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node1','policyversion1');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node1','policyversion2');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyOnNode values ('node2','policyversion1');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversion1','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyVersion values ('policyversion2','policyid2');

insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy A','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy B','policyid1');
insert into OV_PM_Policy values ('policy C','policyid2');

insert into OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment values ('policyid1','18681abc-097d-41cd-9782-e28d9a9f5fc4');
insert into OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment values ('policyid2','18681abc-097d-41cd-9782-e28d9a9f5fc4');
```

Query:

```
    select MN.name as nodeName, P.name as policyName
    FROM OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment PGA
    left join OV_PM_Policy P on PGA.PolicyId = P.PolicyId
    left join OV_PM_PolicyVersion PV on P.PolicyId = PV.policyid
    cross join sto_ov_managednode MN

 where PGA.GroupId = 'Base Windows'
    except
    select MN.name as nodeName, P.name as policyName
    from sto_ov_managednode MN
    left join OV_PM_PolicyOnNode PON on pon.nodeid = mn.name
    left join OV_PM_PolicyVersion PV on PV.policyversionid = pon.policyversionid
    left join OV_PM_Policy P on P.PolicyId = pv.policyid
    left join OV_PM_PolicyGroupAssignment PGA on P.PolicyId = PGA.PolicyId
    where PGA.GroupId = 'Base Windows'
    order by nodeName, policyName;
```

The top part of the query gets all of the policies for the policy group and does a cross join with the nodes to list one policy for each node regardless of whether the policy exists or not.  Then I use EXCEPT to remove the existing node policies.

Result:

```
nodeName    policyName
node2       policy C
```

Comment: I really appreciate you taking the time in an attempt to replicate the schema..and kodos.. on getting it basically right...I've the sqlfiddle you did a bit...I'll post as an update to my question so you can see it.

Comment: Ok... I'll translate your sample into my real case and let you know. thanks